# enable ldap for wekan

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

Trying to setup wekan simply using snap on ubuntu server. 
what I am doing is simply enable ldap by instruction:

```
Ldap Enable.
To enable the ldap of Wekan:
        $ snap set wekan LDAP_ENABLE='true'
        -Disable the ldap of Wekan:
        $ snap set wekan LDAP_ENABLE='false'
```

And getting error:
snap set wekan LDAP_ENABLE='true'
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "wekan" snap (invalid option name: "LDAP_ENABLE")

https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/LDAP

Has anybody experience with wekan project and ldap setup?

Comment: Maybe related (https://github.com/wekan/wekan/issues/119), but try updating to the latest wekan and retry if you haven't

Comment: Problem was that correct way specify this setting is to use (ldap-enable) for each parameter. Not like specified in MAN page.

Comment: Add an answer with the applicable detail with more detail and explain what resolved the issue specifically for you and that will help ensure your post stays as helpful as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You used settings key names in wrong format.

https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/Adding-new-Snap-settings-to-code#changes-to-snap-help

"Snap settings need to be lowercase, and inside single quotes."

Replace uppercase letters to lowercase and underscores to dashes.

```
echo "LDAP_ENABLE"| tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"| sed 's/_/\-/g'
```